# Laravel asset() method not working if I installed in sub-directory instead of absolute url

Tags: php, laravel

This is not finding the assets from the public directory.

I installed laravel in subdirectory like:

http://localhost/yourproject

how can I fix this?

Comment: What's your APP_URL set to in .env?

Comment: http://localhost

Comment: Well... do you see the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asset() helper uses the app url.  This is defined in `.env`.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost/yourproject
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding `ASSET_URL=public` to `.env` file helped me.

Answer (score 2):

This work for me:
.env

```
ASSET_URL=http://localhost/yourproject
```